# Purrring several regression methods in a plot [data included]

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, lm, nls

**TL;DR** 
**[**

x I'm purring a scatter plot for each species in a tibble with two types of regressions superimposed. Shows height predicted by diameter for trees.

x `nls` finds multiple possible `data` and fails to compute `geom_smooth` - a tidyeval error?

x I'm not sure how to use a user defined function with 'map2'.

**]**

A sample of my dataframe, `train.data`, is attached as a `dput`output at the end of the message.

I've split my data into a test set (20%) and a training set (80%). I've calculated summaries for the linear and non-linear models earlier and made a plot with the predicted values versus the estimated values. But I'd like a graph with the curve for the estimated models (linear and non-linear), and if I've understood it correctly, `ggplot2` should come to the same conclusion as `nls` and `lm`? A tidyverse way to include offset (same for all observations) in the tibble instead of in the data.frame would be very welcome.

*First, creating plotting function to map. NLS is red, LM is blue.*

```
double_mapper <- function(x, colname) {
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x=dia, y=Height)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  ggtitle(label = colname)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank())+
  geom_smooth(method="nls",
              formula= Height ~ -1 +I(dia^2)/I((a+b*dia)^2),
              method.args = list(offset=offset, 
                                 start = list(a=10, b=0.2), #Earlier study solution
                                 se=F),
              color="red")+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",
              formula= Height ~ -1 + dia,
              method.args= list(offset=offset),
              color="blue"
  )
}
```

*Create a tibble with nested species and create a graph for each.*

```
mixed_df_test <- train.data %>%
  group_by(SPP) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(graphs=map2(.x = data,.y = SPP, partial(double_mapper,
                                                 x= .x,
                                                 colname=.y)))

plots_model_mixed <- ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = mixed_df_test$graphs, common.legend=TRUE,legend = "top",ncol = 2,nrow = 4)
```

Error messages:

*from `map2`*

```
Error in (function (x, colname)  : unused arguments (.x[[1]], .y[[1]])
```

*from `nls`*

```
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
parameters without starting value in 'data': Height, dia
```

dput of train.data:

```
structure(list(SPP = c("Abies sibirica", "Abies sibirica", "Abies sibirica", 
"Abies sibirica", "Abies sibirica", "Pinus sylvestris", "Pinus sylvestris", 
"Pinus sylvestris", "Pinus sylvestris", "Pinus sylvestris"), 
    Height = c(6, 7.6, 9.9, 6.2, 8.1, 8.3, 7.7, 8.2, 7.8, 9.6
    ), dia = c(74.4580418759451, 96.2808392152873, 115.995689575087, 
    84.4985206971104, 104.498803820905, 141.492049246592, 151.459565561241, 
    177.997190989072, 190.499343830891, 152), offset = c(1.3, 
    1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    SPP = c("Abies sibirica", "Pinus sylvestris"), .rows = list(
        1:5, 6:10)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard, that resolves the error! [EDIT: include tilde ~ before partial]. But I still can't print the plots?
  ```ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = mixed_df_test$graphs, common.legend=TRUE,legend = "top",ncol = 2,nrow = 4)```is empty? 

[Edit to reflect deleted comment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of problems in the original code.

1) You needed a `~` before `partial`. Actually, you didn't need partial in this example.

2) In the formula in `geom_smooth` you have to use `x` and `y` rather than the names of the original variables.

3) You need to tell ggplot where to find the `offset`

4) `se` is an argument to `geom_smooth` not one of the `method.args`

```
double_mapper <- function(x, colname) {
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x=dia, y=Height)) + 
    geom_point(shape=1) + 
    ggtitle(label = colname)+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank())+
     geom_smooth(method="nls",
                 formula = y ~ -1 +I(x^2)/I((a+b*x)^2),
                 method.args = list(offset=x$offset, 
                                    start = list(a=10, b=0.2)), #Earlier study solution
                se = FALSE,
                color="red") +
    geom_smooth(method="lm",
                formula= y ~ -1 + x,
                method.args= list(offset=x$offset),
                color="blue"
    )
}


mixed_df_test <- train.data %>%
  group_by(SPP) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(graphs=map2(.x = data,.y = SPP, ~double_mapper(
                                                 x= .x,
                                                 colname=.y)))

plots_model_mixed <- ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = mixed_df_test$graphs, common.legend=TRUE,legend = "top",ncol = 2,nrow = 4)
plots_model_mixed
```

I am fairly certain that you could use facets rather than multiple plots - this would make much simpler code. I am not sure how to specify the offset though (It might be better to fit the models outside of the plot and provide the fitted values in a data.frame.

If facets don't work, have a look at the `patchwork` package for an easy way to combine plots.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, well spotted! I've tried around with the offset, but I can't really make it work either. Maybe best left for another question tomorrow. I avoided facets as I later add text to each plot, i.e. ```ggpubr::annotate_figure(plots_LM_1,
                        top=text_grob("Linear Model of height versus diameter across all sites", color="black",face="bold",size=14),
                        left=text_grob("Height, m", color="black",face="italic",size=12, rot=90),
                        bottom=text_grob("Diameter, mm", color="black",face="italic",size=12))```